# Iterating through 9 times and I think I have a syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
 @numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

  @numbers.each do |n|              

    if @order.card_type"n" != "none" 
      notes +=  "\n\nCard 1: " + @order.card_type1 + "\nPaper Weight: " + @order.paper_weight1 + "\nQuantity: " + @order.quantity1 + "\nInk Color #1: " + @order.ink_color11 + "\nInk Color #2: " + @order.ink_color12 + "\nWording: " + @order.wording1 + "\nReturn Address Printing: " + @order.return_address1 + "\nGuest Address Printing: " + @order.guest_address1.to_s + "\nEnvelope Liners: " + @order.envelope_liners1                 
    end               

  end
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I need to replace "n" with 1-9 in my controller. I can't figure out the right way to do this.

Comment: change `@order.card_type"n"` to `@order.try("card_type#{n}") 1= 'none'`

Comment: Unrelated, but prefer string interpolation to concatenation. I'd probably also just collect the strings and join them to create the final `notes` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

The first, already solved, is that you'll need a `send` to access the value:

```
if @order.send(:"card_type#{n}") != "none" ...
```

The second is that each of the individual elements inside the string are also numerically-named:

```
Card 1: #{@order.card_type1}
```

Right now you'll be using the same value throughout the loop so you'll need to use `send`:

```
#{@order.send(:"card_type#{n}")}
```

Third, you can clean up the ginormous string concat using a heredoc:

```
if @order.send(:"card_type{n}") != "none" 
  notes += <-EOS
    Card 1: #{@order.card_type1}
    Paper Weight: #{@order.paper_weight1}
    Quantity: #{@order.quantity1}
    Ink Color #1: #{@order.ink_color11}
    Ink Color #2: #{@order.ink_color12}
    Wording: #{@order.wording1}
    Return Address Printing: #{@order.return_address1}
    Guest Address Printing: #{@order.guest_address1.to_s}
    Envelope Liners: #{@order.envelope_liners1}
  EOS
end
```

Fourth, rather than do this, use a collection in the first place, and throw in some helper methods that'll *significantly* clean up your mainline code. Here I'm using POROs but the exact same mechanics apply.

I'm assuming some sort of order item. I shortened the number of attributes for brevity:

```
class OrderItem
  attr_accessor :type, :wording

  def initialize(type, wording)
    @type    = type
    @wording = wording
  end

  def valid_item?
    type != 'none'
  end

  def item_info
    <<-EOS
      Card Type: #{type}
      Wording: #{wording}
    EOS
  end
end
```

An order consists of a collection of those items. (You can limit to nine in a variety of ways, this is not reflected here.)

```
class Order
  attr_accessor :items

  def initialize(items)
    @items = items
  end

  def valid_items
    items.find_all &:valid_item?
  end
end
```

In a Rails app each of these would be ActiveRecord models, stored in the DB.

To simulate an order I'm creating them manually and making sure one has the `"none"` type:

```
items         = 4.times.collect { |n| OrderItem.new('not none', "wording #{n}") }
items[2].type = 'none'

order = Order.new(items)
```

To get a string containing the order info for non-"none" types:

```
output = order.valid_items.collect(&:item_info).join("\n--\n")
```

And if you print that out:

```
  Card Type: not none
  Wording: wording 0

--
  Card Type: not none
  Wording: wording 1

--
  Card Type: not none
  Wording: wording 3
```

Note the order item I set to "none" doesn't appear.

Now, I've taken liberties with naming (not knowing your domain) and there are various tweaks you'll need to make (like... why generate text output in a Rails app), but this shows one possible path you could take to clean up the code, and reduce the amount of thought it takes to understand the mainline code.

Even if you don't separate out the order items and stick with the numerically-named order attributes you can still isolate the confusing code to pull out the number-based attributes, figure out which ones are necessary (e.g., spin through the card types and get an array of the numbers that aren't `none` and use that to access all the other fields).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a thorough and lengthy reply. I am going to study this and implement it into my code. Such a great learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

Just access it with `[]` notation and string manipulation:

```
(1..9).each do |n|              

  if @order["card_type#{n}"] != "none" 
    # ...
  end               

end
```

Failing that, you can also do:

```
@order.send("card_type#{n}")
```

Comment: I am getting undefined method `[]' error? Am I missing something.

Comment: @CraigRinde The `@order` is `nil`. Can you do `@order.inspect` and post your output?

Comment: Try `@order.send("card_type#{n}")`

Comment: you can try `@numbers = (0..9)` too instead of typing them all out

Comment: @Edmund Thanks - added your suggestion

Comment: @CraigRinde Is `@order` an array? I was under the impression that it was an object. Thus the `send("card_type#{n}")

Comment: @TheSpurg It depends. If it was an ActiveRecord object `[]` would work fine. Doesn't have to be an array to work.

Comment: @sjagr Agreed, but I didn't want to assume

Comment: @CraigRinde Also unrelated, but it might make more sense to have the cards in an array and avoid having to use `send`. Then you could also just write `9.times do |n| ...etc...`. Then do a find_all or grep and collect the strings. This is more functional and ultimately easier to reason about. And refactor the note creation. Or at least use a heredoc.

Comment: @TheSpurg Wiki'ed and added your suggestion - I don't like assuming either but there wasn't much to work with in the question!

Comment: @CraigRinde Actually, now that I see that you'll have to use `send` to create the note as well, this is a prime candidate for a re-thinking instead of doing all this manual work. If nothing else you should move the note creation into the `Order` class and avoid almost *all* of this busy-work.

Comment: @sjagr Note that the `send` methodology will need to be used *throughout* the string concatenation; this is tedious and error-prone. It's right in the limited sense that in the end it'll work, but it's ugly, brittle, and difficult to think about :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I am still learning so I am hacking this together and I am sure it is not the best way to do it. Do you have anything I could read on the strategy you are suggesting? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CraigRinde It's basic OOP, really; what you *seem* to have is an order consisting of multiple line items. This implies each item is an instance of its own class (e.g., in Rails, a `has_many` of some sort). This makes the resulting code trivial--example coming in an (non-Rails) answer since too long to comment.